# Random samples from createFolds in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I want to split my dataset into 30 folds. So I used `createFolds` function from `caret` package in R. I `set.seed` to have reproducible results.

Now, I want to have 20 different random samples. In other words, 20 different 30 folds. Thus, I need to change the `set.seed` 20 times.

Is there a way to make this easier.

```
    wdbcc=as.data.frame(scale(wdbc))
    set.seed(12345)
    k = 30
    folds <- createFolds(wdbcc$PE, k = k, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
```

**NOTE**

`wdbcc` is my dataset, `k` is the number of the fold, `PE` is the dependent variable.

**EDIT1**

I will give a brief example of what I want as follows

First I will use the following set.seed

```
  wdbcc=as.data.frame(scale(wdbc))
    set.seed(12345)
    k = 30
    folds <- createFolds(wdbcc$PE, k = k, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
```

Then, I will build the model on that folds split as

```
 lm = list()
        for (i in 1:k) {
          lm[[i]] = lm(PE~ ., data = wdbcc[folds[[i]],])
        }
```

Then, I will use the same idea but with changing of set.seed to (123456) instead of (12345), and build the model on that.

I need to do that 20 times with different set.seed. Each time to build the model on different set.seed.

**EDIT2**

Simply, If I have 30 folds I will build the linear regression on those 30 folds and thus I will have 30 model results. I need to have the same process but with different 30 folds (20 times and each one of the 20 I have different 30 folds) So, I will build the model each time of the 20 on 30 different folds.

Comment: Can you maybe add minimal reproducible example? And furthermore: where does the `createFolds()` function come from? It is not Base R as far as I get it.

Comment: @Georgery, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
folds <- replicate(20,createFolds(wdbcc$PE, k = k, list = FALSE, returnTrain = TRUE))
```

if you do not mind having the folds in a vector (columns of the matrix) and not in a list.

**Edit:** my code above already ensures seeded random numbers, since you will get the same folds (all 20 of them) every time you run the above code with a given seed. However, if you absolutely want to have a specific seed for every resample (which is suspicious), you can do the following

```
wdbcc=as.data.frame(scale(wdbc))
lmv = vector("list",20)
mySeed=c(1,2,3,4,5,...,20) #vector with your pre-defined seeds

for (i in 1:length(lmv)) {
    set.seed(mySeed[i])
    lmv2 = vector("list",30)
    folds <- createFolds(wdbcc$PE, k = 30, list = FALSE, returnTrain = TRUE)
    for (j in 1:length(lmv2)) {
        lmv2[[j]] = lm(PE~ ., data = wdbcc[folds!=j,])
    }
    lmv[[i]] = lmv2
}
```

Comment: @ser2974951, thanks, but I need to specify my set.seed because my idea is to use each 30 fold of 20 random samples with different linear regressions.

Comment: @jeza I don't understand, do you want to use specific set.seeds for each and every one of the 20 resamples? Or do you just want to have seeded samples? If the second then my code will achieve that, if you use a specific seed you will always get the same result with my code.

Comment: thanks but this does not give me the idea I need. Simply, If I have 30 folds I will build the linear regression on those 30 folds and thus I will have 30 model results. I need to have the same process but with different 30 folds (20 times and each one of the 20 I have different 30 folds) So, I will build the model each time of the 20 on 30 different folds.

Comment: @jeza If the new edit doesn't answer your question then I don't know what will. I've given you enough hints that you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: @jeza Do you actually need to have 30 different sets of folds, or simply 30 different folds? I ask since having 30 different seeds for 30 different sets of folds may not just be unnecessary but no longer random (pseudorandom instead). For a more detailed explanation, see this Stata guide on their equivalent command explains it well, p3 "Do not set the seed too often": https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rsetseed.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The createFolds might not work as expected:

```
folds <- replicate(20,createFolds(wdbcc$PE, k = k, list = FALSE, returnTrain = TRUE))
```

It will return the train only if list = TRUE, according to the doc:

> returnTrain   a logical. When true, the values returned are the sample positions corresponding to the data used during training. **This argument only works in conjunction with list = TRUE**